# Make sprites fixate to their positions

Tags: java, animation, javafx, java-8, sprite

I am making a clone of Pokemon in java and I have a Character main (player character), Trainers trainer, a BufferedImage im, and a GraphicsContext gc. What I am trying to accomplish is making the trainer sprites fixate to their specific map location rather than the screen position. My code works for the horizontal but not vertical. Any help would be appreciated. I can explain more as necessary. Other helpers: width is screen width, and height is screen height. As an example of what I'd like the trainer to do: when the character is at a point where the map is no longer scrolling, then it shouldn't move with the character. Else, it should (but I don't know how!)

```
main.setPosx(main.getPosx() + main.getSprite().getVelocityX() * t);
main.setPosy(main.getPosy() + main.getSprite().getVelocityY() * t);
for (Trainer trainer : map.getTrainers()) {
    trainer.setPosx(trainer.getPosx() + trainer.getSprite().getVelocityX() * t);
    trainer.setPosy(trainer.getPosy() + trainer.getSprite().getVelocityY() * t);
}
main.getSprite().setPosition(main.getPosx() * (width / im.getWidth()),
        main.getPosy() * (height / im.getHeight()));

/*where the problem is*/
for (Trainer trainer : map.getTrainers()) {
    trainer.getSprite().setPosition(
            ((trainer.getPosx() - (int) (main.getPosx() - width / 4 < 0 ? 0
                    : main.getPosx() > im.getWidth() - width / 4
                            ? im.getWidth() - width / 2
                            : main.getPosx() - width / 4))
                              * (width / im.getWidth())),
            ((trainer.getPosy() - (int) (main.getPosy() - height / 4 < 0 ? 0
                    : main.getPosy() > im.getHeight() - height / 4
                            ? im.getHeight() - height / 2
                            : main.getPosy() - height / 4))
                              * (height / im.getHeight())));
}

gc.clearRect(0, 0, width, height);
gc.drawImage(SwingFXUtils.toFXImage(im.getSubimage((int) (main.getPosx() - width / 4 < 0 ? 0
        : main.getPosx() > im.getWidth() - width / 4 ? im.getWidth() - width / 2
                : main.getPosx() - width / 4),
        (int) (main.getPosy() - height / 4 < 0 ? 0
                : main.getPosy() > im.getHeight() - height / 4 ? im.getHeight() - height / 2
                        : main.getPosy() - height / 4),
        (int) width / 2, (int) height / 2), null), 0D, 0D, width, height);
```

Comment: Stop deleting and reposting your question again and again. If other users tell you that your question needs improvement, *improve* your question.

Comment: I added more than what was requested in the improvement comments, of which there was only one.

Comment: The point is you should not delete and repost. [Edit] your question in response to requests for improvement. You should also read [how to ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and especially how to create a [MCVE]. There is not enough information in the question to be able to provide an answer at present: I strongly recommend creating (from scratch if necessary) a minimal example that demonstrates the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed with

```
                trainer.getSprite().setPosition(
                        (trainer.getPosx() - (main.getPosx() < width / 4 ? width / 4
                                : main.getPosx() > im.getWidth() - width / 4 ? im.getWidth() - width / 4
                                        : main.getPosx()))
                                * 2 + width / 2,
                        (trainer.getPosy() - (main.getPosy() < height / 4 ? height / 4
                                : main.getPosy() > im.getHeight() - height / 4 ? im.getHeight() - height / 4
                                        : main.getPosy()))
                                * 2 + height / 2);
```